# A necessary condition for a smooth map to be a local isometry - why should the integrands be equal?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry

This is theorem $6.2.2$ - page $127$ of Pressley's Elementary Differential Geometry:

> A smooth map $f:S_1 \subset \Bbb R^3 \to S_2 \subset \Bbb R^3$ is a local isometry if and only if the symmetric bilinear forms $\langle \cdot , \cdot\rangle_p$ and $f^* \langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle_p$ on $T_p S_1$ are equal for all $p \in S_1$.

The author defines $f^* \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_p$ as the symmetric bilinear form $(v,w) \in T_p S_1 \times T_p S_1  \mapsto f^*\langle v, w \rangle_p = \langle D_p f(v), D_p f(w) \rangle_{f(p)} $. Where, $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle_p$ is defined for $p \in S$ as just the dot product in $\Bbb R^3$ but restricted to $T_pS$.

The basic idea is that if $\gamma$ is a curve in $S_1$, then the length of $\gamma$ is:

$$\ell(\gamma) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \langle \dot \gamma(t), \dot \gamma(t) \rangle_{\gamma(t)}^{1/2} dt \ \ \ \ (1)$$

and the length of the image of $\gamma$ by $f$ is:

$$\ell(f \circ \gamma) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} \langle D_{\gamma(t)} f(\dot \gamma(t)),D_{\gamma(t)} f(\dot \gamma(t))\rangle_{\gamma(t)}^{1/2} dt = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} f^*\langle \dot \gamma(t), \dot \gamma(t)\rangle_{\gamma(t)}^{1/2}dt \ \ \ \ (2)$$

so, obviously if these two bilinear form are the same at every point, the integrals are equal and we get that $f$ is a local isometry.

However, for the other direction, the author writes (along the lines of) the following:

"Conversely, suppose that the integrals in $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equal for all curves $\gamma$ in $S_1$. **Then, the integrands must be the same for all $\gamma$**. Since any tangent vector $v$ to $S_1$ is the tangent vector of a curve on $S_1$, it follows that $\langle v, v\rangle = f^* \langle v, v \rangle$ for all $v$, and since these two are symmetric bilinear form they must then be equal".

I just don't see why the integrands must be equal as claimed. It seems rather like a basic calculus question, but I am not sure. The difference between the integrands is a continuous function, but it is not necessarily nonnegative (as far as I can see). Can someone explain how to obtain this result?

Comment: This is similar to the Fundamental Lemma of Calculus of Variations, and you can prove it by absurd: Suppose there was some $\gamma$ for which the integrands are not equal. Then one of them is larger than the other on some open set. Restricting $\gamma$ to this open set, we get a new curve, but the integrals are different.

Comment: @LUizCordeiro thanks!